# Clausula COUNT(1) y DENSE_RANK()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta en sql server, el objetivo es traer los registros de la tabla `Personas` que esten relacionados a `ListaMarketing_persona` pero como esta es una tabla de AnyToAny que une a `ListaMarketing`, puede que haya varias personas relacionadas a varialas listasMark. mi consulta era la siguiente:

```
SELECT  
    distinc
    p.Id,
    p.Nombres,
    p.ApellidoPaterno, 
    p.ApellidoMaterno, 
    count(1) over (partition by null) TotalRegistros, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over ( ORDER BY p.FechaActualizacion DESC ) AS RowNum, 
FROM Personas as p 
    inner join Estados as e on p.EstadoId=e.Id
    inner join ListaMarketing_Persona as lmpe on p.Id=lmpe.IdPersona
    inner join ListaMarketing as lm on lmpe.IdListaMarketing=lm.Id 

where lmpe.IdListaMarketing in (select Id from @Temp_LstMark)
```

Con el `distinc` logro evitar los duplicados, pero, necesito el `ROw_NUMBER()` pero este hace que suceda eso:

```
ID      Nombres      ApellidoPate ApellidoMate        TotReg ROwNum
170112  Juan         Quispe       Santos              53     22
170111  Vit          Ali          Cruz                53     23
46      SARA         ABIGAILL     HUAHUAMULLO MAMANI  53     24
31      ELIZABETH    QUISPE                           53     25
28      CARLA IONEE  CABANILLAS   GALLARDO            53     26
28      CARLA IONEE  CABANILLAS   GALLARDO            53     27
27      VICTOR ELVIS ALVAREZ                          53     28
```

El `RowNum` Hace que el distinc no funcione, en los datos duplicados, y se duplica el registro de Id **28**

Decidí usar es `DENSE_RANK()`.

```
SELECT  
    distinc
    p.Id,
    --count(1) over (partition by null) TotalRegistros,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY  p.FechaActualizacion DESC) AS RowNum,
```

Este ya no duplica.
pero me tra este resultado:

```
index     ID    Nombres        ApePaterno   ApeMaterno    TotaReg  RowNum
47        33    ELSA           CUAYLA                     53       46 
48        30    JIMY JUAN      CASTILLO     QUISPE        53       47
49        26    ODALIZ SHARON  ALVAREZ      ARREDONDO     53       48
```

Se ve que me tre todos los registros que son un total de **49**, pero el total de registros sigue saliendo **53**

Comment: Hola Vitmar. Toma en cuenta que es practicamente imposible darte una respuesta acertada sin entender el contexto: tus datos. Por favor, provee una muestra de tus datos, el resultado actual con tu consulta, y el resultado deseado.

Comment: Los registros que hay después de dense_rank() son los mismos que había antes... es decir, `count()` no tiene por que variar o realmente no has logrado explicar lo que quieres. Estoy con @sstan, es mejor añadir un ejemplo de entrada y salida deseada.

Comment: @jachguate ya los edite, espero se entienda

Comment: Hola Vitmar. Graciar por querer agregar aclaraciones. Pero simplemente decir que recibes 10 o 12 registros no es lo mismo que proveer una muestra de tus datos. La pregunta no es clara. Es mas, puede que al describir mas claramente tus datos, podamos darte soluciones alternativas a la que pides. Tal vez no hay razon por la que debas tener duplicados, y ese es en realidad el problema. Pero, por ahora, la informacion que nos das es demasiado superficial.

Comment: Agregue una imagen, olvide que en la segunda consulta, estava el `distinc`

Comment: Mas leo tu pregunta, mas estoy convencido que el problema está justamente donde dices que no importa: el `from` y el `where`. El uso de `dense_rank` en tu caso es como tratar de curar el síntoma en vez de ir a la raíz. Te garantizo que hay una mejor solución. Pero para que podamos dartela, tienes que tomar el tiempo de darnos una muestra de los datos en las tablas envueltas, y luego el resultado de hacer tu consulta actual (la imagen no corresponde a tu consulta) + el resultado deseado. No es complicado, pero sí requiere tiempo y esfuerzo de tu parte. La decisión es tuya.

Comment: @sstan, es probable que estemos viendo un caso del [problema xy](http://xyproblem.info/). Por ahora, he intentado dar mi respuesta para Y, veamos que dice el OP al final.

Comment: @jachguate: Es exactamente el caso aquí. Yo también, tengo una respuesta para Y, pero estoy 99% seguro que no es lo que debería hacer OP, asi que, por ahora, me aguanto. Llevo rato pensando que vendría bien hacer una pregunta/respuesta en meta sobre como hacer buenas preguntas de tipo SQL. Así podemos orientar a las personas para que mejoren la calidad de estas preguntas. Tal vez me lanzo en eso.

Comment: jaja, @sstan, por qué te limitas a SQL, amigo, hazla para todos los lenguajes... jajaja :D Creo que lo dicho [acá](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aplica y podría ser suficiente, aunque si quieres podemos ser más específicos en el caso de SQL. Igual estoy inclinado a hacer un post en [meta] sobre las publicaciones que dejan código o datos en imágenes y no en texto plano.

Comment: Ya lo actualice, gracias por su ayuda, si tinenen mejores sugerencias en el uso de los `inner join`, lo agradecere, si es ese el problema... no se me ocurre como mas mostrarles los datos...

Comment: @Vitmar, Volviendo al tema del problema XY, ¿lo que tu necesitas es un listado de las personas que están relacionadas a X listas de marketing?

Comment: asi es @jachguate

Comment: He publicado [esta pregunta en meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1070/21) en relación a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basándome en el estado actual de tu pregunta, yo haría la consulta en 2 etapas:

1. Recuperar la lista de `id` de las personas que me interesan filtrando los duplicados:

   ```
   select distinct IdPersona
     from ListaMarketing_Persona
    where IdListaMarketing in (select Id from @Temp_LstMark)
   ```
2. Hacer un join con `Personas` para el resultado final:

   ```
   ;with cte as (
     select distinct IdPersona
       from ListaMarketing_Persona
      where IdListaMarketing in (select Id from @Temp_LstMark)
   )
   select p.Id,
          p.Nombres,
          p.ApellidoPaterno,
          p.ApellidoMaterno,
          count(*) over () as TotalRegistros,
          row_number() over (order by p.FechaActualizacion desc) as RowNum
     from cte c
     join Personas p
       on p.Id = c.IdPersona
   ```

Debido a que la primera etapa filtra los duplicados, puedes seguir usando `row_number` normalmente.

Como no veo el uso de `Estados` y `ListaMarketing` en tu consulta, los quité. Si en realidad los necesitas, entonces quiere decir que le falta información pertinente a tu pregunta.

Comment: La idea es buena, lo implemente... en dos partes como muestra en su ejemplo, me queda la duda, si puedo hacerlo mas corto la consulta

Comment: @Vitmar: No lo sé. Obviamente, si supiera como hacerla mas corta lo haría. Pero no entiendo la preocupación con que la consulta sea corta o larga. Lo importante es que obtengas buenos resultados, con un rendimiento acceptable y que la consulta se entienda, ¿no? Y creeme.. si piensas que esta consulta es larga, aun no has visto nada :)

Comment: Lo digo larga porque lo mio es un procedimiento con mas de 150 lineas, entonces implementarlo cuesta un poco, se tiene que adaptar "todo".. :)

Answer (score 2):

Debido a estas limitaciones:

- No puedes utilizar una función de ventana como argumento de otra función de ventana
- No puedes utilizar `distinct` dentro de `count` si tiene una clausula `over`

la única manera que se me ocurre de lograr esto es utilizando un CTE: Primero calculas el dense_rank() y luego obtienes el max() de dicho dense_rank, algo en la línea de:

```
with 
t1 as (
          select '1a' id1
union all select '1b'
union all select '1c'
union all select '1d'
union all select '1e'
union all select '1f'
union all select '1g'
)
,
t2 as (
          select '2m' id2, '1a' id1
union all select '2n', '1a'
union all select '2o', '1b'
union all select '2p', '1c'
union all select '2q', '1d'
union all select '2r', '1e'
union all select '2s', '1e'
union all select '2t', '1f'
union all select '2u', '1g'
)
,
CalcRank as (
select   t1.id1
       , t2.id2
       , dense_rank() over (order by t1.id1) the_rank
  from t1 
       inner join t2 on t2.id1 = t1.id1
)
select a.*
       , max(the_rank) over () max_rank 
  from CalcRank a
```

El resultado de esta consulta es:

```
id1  id2  the_rank             max_rank
---- ---- -------------------- --------------------
1a   2n   1                    7
1a   2m   1                    7
1b   2o   2                    7
1c   2p   3                    7
1d   2q   4                    7
1e   2s   5                    7
1e   2r   5                    7
1f   2t   6                    7
1g   2u   7                    7

(9 row(s) affected)
```

como ves, obtenemos nueve registros, el rank  lega hasta 7 y max_rank nos devuelve correctamente 7.

Comment: Gracias, actualice la pregunta, tal vez se entienda mejor...

Comment: Creo que la entiendo bien, revisaste la respuesta? ¿en qué estoy equivocado?

Comment: @Vitmar, entonces, en qué quedamos? De acuerdo a la última edición de tu pregunta, esto es lo que buscas.

Comment: claro, pero pienso que es muy larga, tener que encapsular, toda mi consulta y luego hacerla otra, en realidad mi consulta recupera muchos mas datos y sera muy grande, tal vez mi error esa en el uso de los `inner join`...